# PhpStorm configure to work remotely

Tags: configuration, phpstorm

Hi is there a way for PhpStorm to work directly on a remote server? No local files. Because as of the moment PhpStorm has local files wherein it just automatically uploads all files during save on remote.

My problem is if someone changes something remotely I need to manually download it first before seeing the changes.

Comment: PhpStorm can edit remote files (it will download such file into temp location and upload it back on save) -- https://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2015/04/remote-edit-in-phpstorm-9-eap/ . But note that you will loose lots of functionality as you will have very limited code completion, limited refactoring, no debugging etc -- in such case it's better to use some advanced text editor instead of an IDE -- http://stackoverflow.com/a/36850634/783119

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to fully operate on a remote server. Phpstorm need a local project, which contain the `.idea` folder. You can edit remote files without downloading them to the project folder. But in this case the entire list of features is not available.

For you can be useful the following settings:

tools->Deployment->Options:

- warn when uploading over newer file
- Notify about remote changes