# PhpStorm : accessing remote project files without copying files locally

Tags: ide, phpstorm, remote-server

When setting a new project from existing remote files, PhpStorm copy them locally.

Is it possible to access and modify files from remote server without copying them locally , as Eclipse RSE plugin do?

Comment: Yes (not sure how similar it is to RSE plugin though) -- https://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2015/04/remote-edit-in-phpstorm-9-eap/ Notes/Drawbacks: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36850634/783119

Comment: mmm dont quite get "double click the file name or select Edit Remote File from the file context menu:" before importing the project and thus copy locally

Comment: The project must be created in any case (otherwise -- how to know what (S)FTP details to use etc). The logic is simple: 1) create empty new project 2) configure deployment entry and mark it as Default for this project 3) use "Remote Host" panel to browse your remote files and edit them. In the end all what you will have is a local empty project with `.idea` folder (project settings) only.