# Use PhpStorm to remotely edit files that I currently SSH into & edit using vim

Tags: vim, ssh, phpstorm, text-editor

Our current setup at work means that I have to SSH into a development server and then edit files on the dev server directly through the terminal using vim. I personally hate this method and would prefer to use PhpStorm or another popular PHP text editor and edit using this instead.

Is it possible to have PhpStorm automatically SSH into a dev server and edit these files rather than going through the Vim app (which I find confusing)

Comment: Yes it's possible. Just google "phpstorm ssh" and you should find what you are looking for :)

Comment: Setup SFTP deployment and use Remote Editing: https://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2015/04/remote-edit-in-phpstorm-9-eap/ Notes/Drawbacks (remote editing in general): http://stackoverflow.com/a/36850634/783119