# Namespaces not resolving in PhpStorm (Symfony 2.8)

Tags: php, symfony, namespaces, phpstorm

I'm having some difficulty with PhpStorm picking up my namespaces and use statements in a Symfony 2.8 project. In the past it's been OK, mainly when working locally, but this time I'm working on a development server rather than my local machine.

In this example, my `User` entity is extending the `FOSUserBundle` class and I am including this and Doctrine like so:

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
```

Although the top most use statement has a green mark underneath (Undefined Namespace) and, subsequently, it states that the `User` class is undefined too. The `FOSUserBundle` was installed via command line, in the usual way with composer require.

This causes me some problems as normally it would be easy to jump to the abstract class and / or included classes within PhpStorm but it's like it's no longer recognising them.

I've tried to Invalidate Cache / Restart as someone else suggested on here but the problem remains.

If anyone has any ideas as to why this may be happening, I would be grateful to hear them.

Comment: Did you mark your vendors as source files ?

Comment: Not sure what this means. I'm working remotely, not locally.

Comment: In your project settings, you can make the vendor directory as a source root - that'll tell PHPStorm to use it as a namespace root, and as such you'll get the classes in there as autocomplete suggestions. Or you can right click the vendor directory and select "Mark directory as -> sources root"

Comment: It seems I can only do this for local files, so I just downloaded all the server files and I guess I'll work from local and upload when I edit them. I don't think it's possible to set up source roots on the remote host - I don't get that option when I right click anyway.

Comment: You have to have all your code locally (well, at least the most important parts of it) -- IDE cannot index your code that is available on Remote host only. http://stackoverflow.com/a/36850634/783119