# PhpStorm reopen last used remote host files

Tags: php, ide, phpstorm

I've decided to change my main editor from Eclipse to PhpStorm and everything is great with the new editor except that I can't seem to find the option which would reopen my open remote host files after I close the editor. In Eclipse this option was enabled by default. After I reopened Eclipse, all my opened files (for ex. 5 .php files) before closing was there.

I would be very grateful if anybody could help me with this little problem of mine.

Comment: What do you mean by "remote" exactly? Are you doing Remote Edit directly over (S)FTP?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I'm editing files trough FTP.

Comment: When you launch PhpStorm -- will it open your last opened project? If no -- see answer below from @Barmar. In any case -- I doubt that PhpStorm will re-open those files. When you open such files (direct edit over FTP) PhpStorm downloads that file somewhere outside of the project (IDE's temp folder or so) -- AFAIK IDE does not re-open non-project files on project opening (but I can be wrong here). **P.S.** On related note: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36850634/783119

Comment: It opens last opened project but it's not what I need. Your answer and link to related question is what I needed. To be exact "When you open such files (direct edit over FTP) PhpStorm downloads that file somewhere outside of the project".
 I will accept your comment as an answer if you turn it into answer like.

Answer (score 1):

It's **Preferences** -> **Appearance & Behavior** -> **System Settings** -> **Reopen last project on startup**

The name is misleading -- it actually opens *all* your projects.

I think this os the default -- I remember unchecking it because I sometimes have a half dozen projects open and I didn't want to wait for it to reopen all of them when I restart it.