# "Real remote" FTP project with PhpStorm

Tags: ftp, phpstorm

Presently I'm using phpDesigner 8. I like, it can create a "real remote" FTP project, phpDesigner not downloading all project files to local, it shows me the remote tree, and I download only the file, that I'd like to edit. When I save, the file automatically uploaded with FTP.

I'd like to do this with PhpStorm. I tried "New Project from Existing Files", then "Web server is on remote host, files are accessible via FTP/SFTP/FTPS". I turn on Tools/Deployment/Automatic Upload (always), and PhpStorm immediately uploads the saved files via FTP. This good. But I don't need a local copy any of the remote files. I need to download the remote files only to editor, not to locally, and saves to remote.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there any way to do this?

Well ... you cannot create 100% Remote FTP project -- because you still have to create actual project ... which has to be local. It can be completely empty (no actual project files) but it will still contain config files in `.idea` subfolder (e.g. your FTP details).

But yes -- once such empty project created -- just go to `Settings/Preferences` and configure Deployment.

Once it's properly set up -- go browse Remote Host and choose to edit file remotely -- IDE will download that file in *temp location* and upload it back as needed -- https://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2015/04/remote-edit-in-phpstorm-9-eap/.

**NOTE:** missing stuff when editing remotely -- https://stackoverflow.com/a/36850634/783119