# Search in all project files on remote host in PhpStorm

Tags: file, search, phpstorm, remote-host

I have lots of files in a project on a remote host and I want to find out from which file another php file is called. Is it possible to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> search on a remote host project?

Comment: No. In order for execute search file must be downloaded first. Therefore it's better to download whole project (needed files) locally and then execute local search. If you need to execute remote search -- better use SSH to connect to such host and execute search there remotely.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is it possible to use `Ctrl+Shift+F` search on a remote host project?

**Currently it's not possible.** (*2022-06-09: now possible with remote development using JetBrains Gateway, see at the end*)

- In order to execute search in a file content in a locally run IDE such file must be read first. For that the IDE must download it... which can be quite time & connection consuming task for (S)FTP connections (depends on how far the server is; how fast your connection; bandwidth limits etc.)
- Even if the IDE could do it transparently for search like it does with Remote Edit functionality (where it downloads a remote file but instead of placing it in the actual project it stores it in a temp location) *it still needs to download it.*
- If you execute one search (one term) and then need to do another search (slightly modified term or completely different search string) the IDE would need to *re-download those files again* (waste of time and connection).

Therefore it makes much more sense to download your project (all or desired files only) locally and then execute such search(es) on local files.

---

If it has to be **purely remote search** (when nothing gets downloaded locally)... then you just establish SSH/RDP/etc connection to that remote host (BTW: PhpStorm has built-in SSH Console functionality) and execute such search directly on the remote server with OS native tools (find/grep and alike) or some remote software (e.g. `mc` or `notepad++`).

---

**P.S. (on related note)**

Some of the disadvantages when doing Remote Edit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36850634/783119

---

**EDIT 2022-06-09:**

BTW, JetBrains now has **JetBrains Gateway** for remote development where you run the IDE core on a remote server and connect to it via SSH using a local dedicated app or a plugin to your IDE (PhpStorm comes bundled with such a plugin since 2021.3 version).

To check more on JetBrains Gateway:

- https://www.jetbrains.com/remote-development/gateway/
- https://blog.jetbrains.com/blog/2021/11/29/introducing-remote-development-for-jetbrains-ides/